# Google Map Street view in Iphone app

Tags: iphone

Can we use Street View in MKMapKit?
it is with iphone google map application.
Can we integrate in our application if now why?

Comment: If you are happy with my answer, I'd appreciate it if you marked it as accepted.

Answer (score 12):

I've managed to implement this using the javascript Google Maps API. The performance is great on the iPhone 4, reasonable on the 3GS, but not really usable on the 3G because it's just too slow. It's a little hacky and far from ideal, but should get the job done if you're in a pinch.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=320,user-scalable=no'/>
        <script src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false' type='text/javascript'></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('p'),{position:new google.maps.LatLng(37.77, -122.41)});" style='padding:0px;margin:0px;'>
        <div id='p' style='height:100%;width:100%;'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this solution certainly works (I was surprised!) performance on my iPhone 4 (over 3G) was beyond sluggish and not anything I would consider usable in a public-facing application.

Answer (score 6):

The current MapKit API for iPhone does not include access to Street View.

The full list of available features are available here: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/index.html