# iPhone : Using Streetview (as in Trip Advisor)

Tags: iphone, augmented-reality, google-street-view

I know the mapkit does not support street view but it is possible to render it in a web control (as shown in another stackoverflow post: [Google Map Street view in Iphone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628711/google-map-street-view-in-iphone-app)).

However, in the Trip Adviser app, they have mashed it up with a A.R control.
Again, I can probably do the AR bit but how do I get the angle from street view.  E.g, what the user is facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TripAdvisor have answered your question: http://tech.tripadvisor.com/2011/02/augmented-reality-on-ipad-project.html.

Pin Positioning is described in the blog post.